# Django pass to an url a list of parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

In my dhango project i create a function callable via url:

```
url(r'^pd/(?P<c_id>[\w\-]+)\/$', calc_q),
```

So my function need to manage at least 4 input

```
@csrf_exempt
def calc_q(request, c_id):

    start_d = datetime.date(2021, 6, 28)
    end_d = datetime.date(2021, 6, 29)
    v_id = 17
    q_time ="15min"
    ...
```

How can i pass, for example a list or a dict from url to my function with my 4 variables inside?
Is possible pass all variables directly in url?
Whitch is the best method?

So many thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know about how to pass a list in URL but you can get your list using a POST request for example `request.POST.getlist('your_input_name')`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in the following manner :

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^pd/(?P<c_id>[\w\-]+)\(?P<value>\d+)/$', calc_q)
```

**then in your template**

```
<a href="{% url 'name_url' value=0 %}">my link</a>
```

**In your view:**

```
@csrf_exempt
def calc_q(request, c_id, value):

    start_d = datetime.date(2021, 6, 28)
    end_d = datetime.date(2021, 6, 29)
    v_id = 17
    q_time ="15min"
    ...
```